# How to see past DNS record history

Tags: dns, whois

A company I am about to do business with has a domain that is less than 1 year old per WHOIS, but they are supposed to be very old. When questioned, they say that their website is very old but their domain name had expired and they had to get it again, and this is why the WHOIS shows it as so young.

Does this make sense? If so is it possible to see past WHOIS records of this domain? This site is not on Wayback Machine.

Comment: This would be up to the registrar to keep.  There isn't an official or even unofficial history of domain registrations, what information is provided, is the only information accessible.  If you are worried about their legitimacy, go another route, request information to prove when the company was incorporated.  **The domain registration isn't really a valid source of information, if you looked up a domain I owned, it wouldn't be registered to anyone that actually exists.**

Comment: @Ramhound: Which, incidentally, violates ICANN's [policies](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/whois-data-accuracy-2017-06-20-en) on domain registration.

Comment: @grawity - I am aware of the requirements.  You can also hide your real information for a price.  Additionally, in my experience, very little verification of the information is provided anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the site is not on the Wayback Machine is already a red flag.
A "very old" website has an excellent chance of being recorded at least once.
I would suggest that you ask them for proof of existence,
since services that provide historical DNS information are usually commercial.

To answer the question, here are some such services (which I have never used).
They are not guaranteed to provide information about all registrars
and every website.

- [Hoster Stats](http://www.hosterstats.com/) :
  Free and providing history starting from the year 2000.
- [Whois History](http://research.domaintools.com/research/whois-history/) :
  Not free but gives freely some information which may be enough.
- [who.is](https://who.is/)
- [domaintools.com](http://domaintools.com/)
- [whoisology.com](https://whoisology.com/)
- [domainIQ](https://www.domainiq.com/)

Comment: Hoster stats worked well

Comment: I found some useful historical DNS data today for a domain I wanted history about from https://securitytrails.com/ ... might be worth adding to the list.

Answer (score 2):

I can add one more to [the @harrymc list](https://superuser.com/a/1321544).

https://completedns.com/dns-history/ - 5 free check per day, also offers paid plans with API and bulk check - I have used this one.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, services such as "completedns" and most from [the @harrymc list](https://superuser.com/a/1321544) have very least data. I suppose it's not a scanning problem, just DB is not so large.

"Whois History" which is actually a "Domaintools" - is not free and ain't cheap. I would recommend use tool suggested by @lindes - "securitytrails".

**SecurityTrails** (registration needed): https://securitytrails.com/domain/

Answer (score 0):

Another excellent (and free) domain history checker is [WHOISrequest’s domain history checker](https://whoisrequest.com/history/).

> “Do you want to know if certain domain name was registered before? We track nameserver changes since 2002 for all COM, NET, ORG, INFO, BIZ and US domains.”